# Modal FormPanel & DatePicker & MessageBox, how to manage masks

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, web

I'm having some problems with the following scenario :

- I have a nested list which has a detailCard.
- When I click the detailCard I pop a FormPanel, now the detailCard is masked.
- FormPanel has a DatePicker, so after selecting a value with the picker I return to the FormPanel but the mask is gone.
- Also when I show a Messabox from the FormPanel I can still click the FormPanel without dismissing the MessageBox.

So I the basic question is, when you show a FormPanel as modal and you have another component which hides the mask on hide, is there a way to manage the mask so it only hides when you close the form?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar problem. It seems that as per the picker shows as modal, when the element is picked, the picker hides any mask.
I've been looking for picker events to handle that, but no luckily yet, so, if you have the answer, please update this thread.

Update: [Solution found]

Just add a listener to the hide "method" of the picker and do what you need to restore the mask.

```
xtype: 'datepickerfield',
name: 'date',
label: 'Date',
picker: {
     listeners: {
          hide: function() {
               // Prevent mask hide default behavior of picker hide event.
               HandleLoadingMask();
          },
     },
},
```

HTH,
Milton.